# Access pandas masks in a dictionary

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary containing several pandas masks as strings for a specific dataframe, but I can't find a way to use those masks.

Here is a short reproducible example :

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'age' : [10, 24, 35, 67], 'strength' : [0 , 3, 9, 4]})

masks = {'old_strong' : "(df['age'] >18) & (df['strength'] >5)",
        'young_weak' : "(df['age'] <18) & (df['strength'] <5)"}
```

And I would like to do something like :

```
df[masks['young_weak']]
```

But since the mask is a string I get the error

```
KeyError: "(df['age'] <18) & (df['strength] <5)"
```

Comment: `df[eval(masks['young_weak'])]` ?   - eval is usually frowned-upon... this would be a last resort probably

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unsafe solution though, and very bad practice, but the only way to solve it is to use `eval`:

```
print(df[eval(masks['young_weak'])])
```

Output:

```
   age  strength
0   10         0
```

Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice) to the reason it's bad.

Comment: I saw this one in the comments, but I get an "EOL while scanning string literal" error when I try this solution

Comment: your missing a closing `quote` after 'strength' in your dict - according to your `KeyError` above

Comment: @vlemaistre Listen to Chris A

Comment: Thanks that was it :)

Answer (score 6):

Use [`DataFrame.query`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) with changed dictionary:

```
masks = {'old_strong' : "(age >18) & (strength >5)",
        'young_weak' : "(age <18) & (strength <5)"}

print (df.query(masks['young_weak']))
   age  strength
0   10         0
```

Comment: Nice one ! But do you know if there is a way to do it without changing the dict, or by changing the dict to transform the strings into masks ?

Comment: @vlemaistre - Unfortunately here is necessary change dictionary.

Comment: Thanks for your answer @jezrael, I'll accept the one with eval() (even though it's less clean that your solution) because it was more of what I was looking for. But this helped me too :)

Comment: @vlemaistre - yes, it is up to you - [Why is using 'eval' a bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1832940/why-is-using-eval-a-bad-practice)

Comment: Just for reference.... `.query` is just using `pd.eval` under the hood anyway according to the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html)...

Comment: @ChrisA - ya, but there are some check, because if change `eval` to `pd.eval` it failed

Comment: @jezrael Your answer is much better that mine, but since his requirements only can be fulfilled with `eval`, i used it, but your answer is very good, you deserve the vote score you have now

Comment: @U9-Forward - yop, maybe you can change your answer like it is posible, but strongly recomended dont do it. ;)

Comment: @jezrael Added a little more to it

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to set up the masks as functions (`lambda` expressions) instead of strings. This works:

```
masks = {'old_strong' : lambda row: (row['age'] >18) & (row['strength'] >5),
    'young_weak' :  lambda row: (row['age'] <18) & (row['strength'] <5)}
df[masks['young_weak']]
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're allowed to change the masks dictionary, the easiest way is to store filters and not strings like this:

```py
masks = {
   'old_strong' : (df['age'] >18) & (df['strength'] >5),
   'young_weak' : (df['age'] <18) & (df['strength'] <5)
}
```

Otherwise, keep the strings and use `df.query(masks['yound_weak'])`.